# Camel lookup RemoteConnectionFactory on Wildfly

Tags: spring, apache-camel, wildfly-8

I'm very new to Apache Camel and completely new to Spring. I'm tryin to send some JMS messages to the embedded hornetq in Wildfly (ver.8.1.0). Here is my code:

```
public class CamelJMS {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        CamelContext cc = new DefaultCamelContext();

         Properties prop = new Properties();
         prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
         "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
         prop.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,
         "org.jboss.jms.jndi.JNDIProviderAdapter");
         prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080");
         prop.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,
         System.getProperty("username", "usr"));
         prop.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,
         System.getProperty("password", "pwd"));

         JndiTemplate jndiT = new JndiTemplate(prop);
         jndiT.bind("ccf", "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
         JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiCFB = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
         jndiCFB.setJndiTemplate(jndiT);
         JmsComponent jmsC = JmsComponent.jmsComponent((ConnectionFactory)jndiCFB.getObject());

         cc.addComponent("jmsrc", jmsC);
         cc.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Go!");
                onException(Throwable.class)
                .handled(true)
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("error.");
                        ((Exception) arg0.getProperty("CamelExceptionCaught", Exception.class)).printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
                from("file:///Users/Foo/Desktop/IN")
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println(arg0.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileAbsolutePath", String.class));
                        System.out.println(arg0.getIn().getBody(String.class));
                    }
                })
                .to("jms:jms/generatoreQueue?connectionFactory=ccf");
            }
        });

        cc.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        cc.stop();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I'm sure about my Wildfly's configuration because I can access the same queue using a non Camel client. When I launch my client I got this error:

```
org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.NamingIOException: Failed to bind [Root exception is java.io.IOException: Internal server error.]
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:49)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$2.execute(Protocol.java:220)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$2.execute(Protocol.java:179)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1.bind(RemoteNamingStoreV1.java:108)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore$2.operation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:288)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore$2.operation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:285)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingOperation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:137)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.bind(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:284)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.bind(RemoteContext.java:133)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.bind(RemoteContext.java:137)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:419)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$2.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:198)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.bind(JndiTemplate.java:196)
at edu.pezzati.camel.jms.broker.CamelJMSBroker.main(CamelJMSBroker.java:38)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Internal server error.
at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingServerV1$MessageReciever$1.run(RemoteNamingServerV1.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Looking to the server log, I found this:

```
...
09:12:02,585 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (default task-5) JBAS011806: Channel end notification received, closing channel Channel ID 793d9f9e (inbound) of Remoting c
onnection 4406e6f5 to /127.0.0.1:49289
09:12:20,121 ERROR [org.jboss.as.naming] (pool-1-thread-1) JBAS011807: Unexpected       internal error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JBAS011859: Naming context is read-only
    at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.requireOwner(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.bind(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:66)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.bind(NamingContext.java:253)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$2.handleServerMessage(Protocol.java:249)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingServerV1$MessageReciever$1.run(RemoteNamingServerV1.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
...
```

Of course I'm misconfiguring something in Spring's `JndiTemplate` but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Wildfly and only a little familiar with JBoss, but you said the configuration parameters should be correct. So based off of my experience configuring the Camel JmsComponent...

Try this:

```
     Properties prop = new Properties();
     prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
     "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
     prop.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,
     "org.jboss.jms.jndi.JNDIProviderAdapter");
     prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080");
     prop.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,
     System.getProperty("username", "usr"));
     prop.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,
     System.getProperty("password", "pwd"));

     Context context = new InitialContext(prop);
     ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");

     JmsComponent jmsC = new JmsComponent(connectionFactory);

     cc.addComponent("jms", jmsC);
```

And change your endpoint to:

```
     .to("jms:queue:generatoreQueue");
```

You shouldn't need the "jms/" in front of the queue name, and the component name should be the same as what you bound it to above in the `addComponent` method.

Comment: Hello, glad to hear you again! Just to make the whole stuff working i changed the line `.to("jms:queue:generatoreQueue");` in `.to("jms:queue:generatoreQueue?username=usr&password=pwd");`. Thankyou again.